# ログイン画面で非表示にしたユーザーでログインできなくなりました

Tags: windows-10

管理者でログインできなくなり大変困っております。
どなたか解決のアドバイスを頂けませんでしょうか。

#### 経緯

紛失時のセキュリティ設定をESET-アンチセプトに沿って行いました。
ユーザーアカウントは2つあります。

①メイン管理者権限アカウント（パスワードあり）
②紛失時用アカウント（パスワードなし）

※ ESET-アンチセプトとは、拾得した人が②にログインすると位置情報やスクリーンショット、内蔵カメラの情報を送信してくれる機能です。

設定が終わり通常使用しておりましたが
※PCを起動すると写真が表示されエンターを押すと①のパスワード入力BOXが表示される状態です。（ユーザー名入力BOXは表示されていない状態）

起動時のログインスクリーン左下に ①,② のアカウントが表示されます。
①の管理者アカウントユーザー名を表示しておく事に抵抗を感じて、以下の記事を参考に非表示のコマンドを実行しました。

[Windows10のサインイン画面に特定のユーザーを表示させない方法](https://4thsight.xyz/290)

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList" /v ユーザー名 /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

これで②だけの表示になってるのだろうと思い再起動すると②に自動ログインされた状態になりました。

ここから①へログインできないことに気付き青ざめて試行錯誤の始まりです。

#### 行った事

1. `> powershell start-process cmd -verb runas`
2. 設定‐更新とセキュリティ―‐回復‐今すぐ再起動‐セーフモードプロンプトで１，と同じコマンド
3. 起動直後 F8 連打。セーフモード起動しませんでした。
4. Windows10のサインイン画面に特定のユーザーを表示させない方法の「非表示にしたユーザーを表示するよう戻す」を実行しましたが管理者権限がないので実行できませんでした。
5. スタートメニューにアカウント切り替えの項目に①のアカウントが表示されておらず切り替えができませんでした。
6. regedit で直接修正を試みましたが管理者権限が無く変更できませんでした。
7. パスワードを設定しようとすると「パスワードは管理者が管理しています。」と表示され設定できませんでした。

#### やりたい事

①のアカウントでログインしたい。

毎日使っておりましたのでユーザー名やパスワードは覚えております。
ユーザー名とパスワードの入力ボックスさえ表示できればログインできるのですが。

どうかアドバイスのほどよろしくお願いいたします。

**環境:**
ノートパソコン　　LG-gram 15Z980-GA55J
エディション　　　Windows 10 Home
バージョン　　　　20H2
OSビルド　　　　　19042.867
エクスペリエンス　Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.551.0

Comment: 標準ユーザーで自動ログインになっているのが気になります。一旦パスワードを設定するとどうなるでしょうか？

Comment: パスワードを変更しようとすると「パスワードは管理者が管理しています。」を表示され変更できませんでした。

Comment: [電源ボタン長押しによる強制終了を３回繰り返すとセーフモードに入れる](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/windows-10-%E3%81%AE%E3%82%BB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%95-%E3%83%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%A7-pc-%E3%82%92%E8%B5%B7%E5%8B%95%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234)かと。

Comment: ②紛失時用アカウントでログインした状態で[CTRL]+[ALT]+[DEL]で、「ユーザーの切り替え」を選択し①メイン管理者権限アカウントに切り替えはできないでしょうか？

Comment: 「ユーザーの切り替え」をクリックしても②のログイン画面になり①を選択できる状態にはなりませんでした。

Comment: sayuriさん！ありがとうございます！！セーフモードでログインできるようになりました。本当にありがとうございました！！！

Answer (score 1):

sayuriさんのアドバイスにより強制終了を三度繰り返すとセーフモードで起動しました。
無事変更を戻すことができました。
又アドバイスを頂いた cubickさん,Yukihiro Hondaさん、他にも一緒に考えて頂いた皆さん本当にありがとうございました。 m(__)m